# Rebuilding indexes in file geodatabase using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, indexing

I am trying to automate the rebuild of file geodatabase indexes using ArcPy v10.6, but I encounter an ERROR 000837 The workspace is not the correct workspace type.

**Question**: **If arcpy.RebuildIndexes_management() works only with Enterprise geodatabases, then how to rebuild indexes in file geodatabases?**

```
import arcpy, os

workspace = "C:/tmp/myDatabase.gdb"
fc = "MyFeatureClass"
arcpy.Exists(workspace)
>>>True
arcpy.Exists(os.path.join(workspace, fc))
>>>True

arcpy.RebuildIndexes_management(workspace, "NO_SYSTEM", [fc], "ALL")
>>>ERROR 000837 The workspace is not the correct workspace type
```

.

Answer (score 2):

That method cannot be used on a file geodatabase, from the tool [help document](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/rebuild-indexes.htm), see usage statement below:

> Data must be from a database or an enterprise, workgroup, or desktop
>   geodatabase. This tool does not work with file or personal
>   geodatabases.

To add an index to an existing feature class within a geodatabase you may use the [Add Attribute Index](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-attribute-index.htm) or [Add Spatial Index](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-spatial-index.htm) method:

Comment: I can't accept your post, because it does not really answer my question

Comment: @BelowtheRadar how does this not answer your question? They explain why that tool does not work ( something easily solved if the help file had been researched) and they provide a solution, the add attribute tool. Suggest you explore the section of the help file about the index tools?

Comment: @Hornbydd because I am asking what is the proper way to rebuild indexes with arcpy inside file geodatabase, not why it's not working with arcpy.RebuildIndexes_management()

Comment: The answer above is the only way to build an attribute index for a file geodatabase.

Comment: I want to rebuild existing indexes, so the answer should be something like, get the indexes infos from the featureClass, drop those indexes and create the indexes again